# Issue with dynamically updating before attribute

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to recreate this image to HTML/CSS/JS: (Using HTML5 semantics)

This is the question that was asked to me:

[image]

Here's my implementation. However, **I am not sure how do I get/update Numbers "30", "19" etc Dynamically?** I'm stuck there, please help.

```css
.endorsements {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-left: 20px solid #49a9e1;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.endorsements::after {
  content: '+'
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section id="endo">
    <button aria-label="css" class="endorsements"> CSS </button>
    <button aria-label="web" class="endorsements"> Web Development </button>
        <button aria-label="SEO" class="endorsements"> SEO </button>
        <button aria-label="HTML" class="endorsements"> HTML </button>
  </section>
</article>
```

**Can someone help me to recreate this spec? I'm not sure using ::after would be a good idea?**

Comment: Is this data stored in a hard coded JavaScript array or in a database (and retrieved using a server side language such as php)? We can’t provide much help unless you give us the background. A picture of the output isn’t much help if we don’t know the question.

Comment: Let's say an array for this example

Comment: Okay. Consider using an object (contrary to my first comment). Look up some methods for looping over it and using that to output HTML. If you get stuck, post another question. Unfortunately, it’s difficult to answer this question without writing the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would build the whole thing up in a `for-loop`, and with "the whole thing", I mean each row.

Add the value to a `data-attribute`, and use `concent: attr(data-attribute)` to display the number.

If you're not creating the HTML structure row by row, do a `document.querySelectAll('.endorsement')` [edit] after you got your data from a server, loop through the response and add each `data-attribute` selectively.

[edit] Also, remove `border-left: 20px solid #49a9e1` from `.endorsement`;

```
.endorsements {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.endorsements::before {
  content: attr(data-number);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #4faadf;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

<!-- Example of how the DOM looks like after javascript have added the attribute 'data-number'. -->

<article>
  <section id="endo">
    <button data-number="30" aria-label="css" class="endorsements"> CSS </button>
    <button data-number="19" aria-label="web" class="endorsements"> Web Development </button>
    <button data-number="18" aria-label="SEO" class="endorsements"> SEO </button>
    <button data-number="13" aria-label="HTML" class="endorsements"> HTML </button>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: This doesn’t help with the “dynamic” part if the numbers change. But the concept coupled with storing their data in an object should help.

Comment: Thank you both of you folks. Trying to understand how this works. Can you elaborate more on what you mean't by 'storing in an object' .. An example would be great since I'm not able to get the complete picture. Trying to learn Vanilla CSS/JS so excuse my noobish questions =))

Comment: This doesn't put the number in the blue square like the image OP posted.

Comment: Sure, can do when I’m not on mobile. Will post in a little while.

Comment: What I meant to show  was the ending HTML, updated through javascript, where `data-number` has been added afterwards with `querySelectoAll`

Answer (score 0):

So as I said in my comment, I'd recommend using something like an object which can be looped over to build your html (Actually, if you were more experienced, I'd recommend something like Angular - it's amazing for stuff like this).

Also note that I wouldn't use a `before::` pseudo element for the number, just put it in a div. See below;

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        let endorsements = {
            0: {
                name     : "CSS",
                count    : 30,
                endorsers:
                    [
                        "link/to/image.png",
                        "link/to/second/image.jpg"
                    ]
            },
            1: {
                name     : "Web Development",
                count    : 16,
                endorsers: [
                    "link/to/image.png",
                    "link/to/second/image.jpg"
                ],
            }
        };

        let html    = "";
        let element = $("#endorsements");

        for (let i in endorsements) {
            html += `<div class="endorsement"><div class="count">${endorsements[i].count}</div><div class="name">${endorsements[i].name}</div></div>`
        }

        element.html(html);
    })
```

```css
.endorsement {
            width            : 100%;
            background-color : #DDDDDD;
            display          : flex;
            align-items      : center;
        }

        .count {
            width            : 30px;
            height           : 30px;
            background-color : #3498DB;
            color            : white;
            text-align       : center;
            line-height      : 30px;
            display          : block;
            float            : left;
            margin-right     : 10px;
        }

        .name::after {
            content : "+";
            color   : #AAAAAA;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="endorsements">

</div>
```